# If we change the orientation mode it reset the GridVIew.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

Hi i'm doing simple demo for grid view. i have issue regarding changing layout.

When my demo working in ladscape mode it store the check box values. but when i change the orientation to any mode. it called onCreate() method again and reset all the values. can anybdy suggest me. how to retain values after the orientation is changes.

Here is my code:

```
btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);


        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, status));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                ImageView imgview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgvew);
                imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_box_checked);
            }

        });



@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {

        if (newConfig.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

        }
    };


@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                status = true;
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, status));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting adapter of your gridview in oncreate put all your code in onResume() it will work correctly..

Comment: 03-07 17:46:50.303: E/AndroidRuntime(1112): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.thumbnail/com.thumbnail.ThumbnailProjectActivity}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.thumbnail/com.thumbnail.ThumbnailProjectActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
03-07 17:46:50.303: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
03-07 17:46:50.303: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
03-07 17:46:50.303: E/AndroidRuntime(1112):  at

Comment: Put super.onResume(); to the end of your overrided onResume method

Answer (score 0):

You need to override two methods:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Read values from the "savedInstanceState"-object and put them in your textview
    if (icicle != null)
    {
       value = icicle.getLong("param");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Save the values you need from your textview into "outState"-object
    outState.putLong("param", value);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put your data into bundle in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` method and restore it in `onCreate` method like this:

```
if(savedInstance!=null){
    savedInstance.getInt(""); //or something you want
}
```